# Is there a way to install the Firebase CLI in a python base docker image?

Tags: python, bash, docker, firebase-cli, firebase-tools

I'm building a python docker image and I need to use the firebase CLI (accessed via os.system commands) in my app. I'm trying to install it by running this in the dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6.8

RUN curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash
```

Getting this output from `docker build -t my_image/firebase`:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : FROM python:3.6.8
 ---> 48c06762acf0
Step 2/2 : RUN curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash
 ---> Running in 11536da1cdb4
-- Checking for existing firebase-tools on PATH...
-- Checking your machine type...
-- Links...
[Binary URL] https://firebase.tools/bin/linux/latest
-- Downloading binary...
bash: line 148: sudo: command not found
-- Setting permissions on binary...
bash: line 154: sudo: command not found
bash: line 163: firebase: command not found
Something went wrong, firebase has not been installed.
Please file a bug with your system information on Github.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/
-- All done!
The command '/bin/sh -c curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Would appreciate any tips about how to do this. Using `RUN npm install -g firebase-tools` is not an option since I'm building on a python image.

Comment: It looks like the error comes from "sudo" not being found. Have you tried installing sudo first?

Comment: Do you want https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python instead?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup suggests that's the right library for server-side applications.  Calling `os.system()` just to make network calls usually isn't good design.

Comment: The "Installation" section on https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools (from the error message) also suggests an alternate path.

Comment: I'm using the firebase CLI to update [deploy targets](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/targets), so sadly the firebase-admin-python (which only "provides Firebase custom authentication support") will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a solution that works. Simply install node on a python image and then use npm to install the firebase-CLI.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6.8

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN npm install -g firebase-tools
```

And now I can run firebase commands from python!

```
import os
command = 'firebase projects:list --token CI_TOKEN'
os.system(command)
```

More info about using the firebase CLI with Continuous Integration can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#cli-ci-systems).

Answer (score -1):

Try to install sudo and giving a user (here, "admin") the sudo rights, before using it:

```
FROM python:3.6.8
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo
RUN useradd admin && echo "admin:admin" | chpasswd && adduser admin sudo
USER admin
RUN curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash
```

Adapted from https://askubuntu.com/questions/906230/run-sudo-command-with-non-root-user-in-docker-container/1168971

Comment: You don't normally need `sudo` in Docker; in the context of a Dockerfile, you can trivially use `USER root` to switch to the root user, and that's usually the default anyways.  It's also one of a handful of administrative commands that just don't work well in Docker (if it asks for a password, there isn't one to give).

Comment: Ran the code per suggestion, ran into this error: ```sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
239 bash: line 163: firebase: command not found
240 Something went wrong, firebase has not been installed.```

Comment: Looking into another option to build a docker image off of node, using npm to install firebase cli, and then adding python.